# How to ask questions in a future tense

Tags: grammar

I noted that some are asked 'When will the meeting be held?' but I'm confused why does some people use "When will be the meeting held?"

What is the correct one?
If only the first sentence is correct, what is the reason for it?

Comment: "When will be the meeting held?" is not grammatical. Who did you hear say that? Is English not their first language?

Comment: thanks a lot, No English is their 2nd language.but how does it correct "What will be held on"? incorrect "When will the meeeting be held'? can please explain it further.

Comment: Reesha, you can *not* say "When will be the meeting held". However, you could ask "What will be held on Monday?" in order to elicit the answer "The meeting".

Comment: Note that the structure depends on the specific verb. For instance, you don't need an auxiliary in _When will the meeting occur?_ or _When will the meeting end?_.

Comment: I'd use shall instead of will...

Comment: Interrogative: when + will + noun + be + past participle is the rule. be held, be seen, be done, be understood for passives. [Please note: people has a plural meaning but takes a singular verb.]

Answer (score 4):

The meeting will be held on Tuesday.

When changing this sentence to a question you place the subject after the first verb
(the auxiliary will) and you get

When will the meeting be held?

Any other position of the verbs is wrong.